# can't do Number increment animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am quite a newbie to JQuery. i got this code from somehere here at stack overflow where
the idea was to create a number animation in jquery.
Now the code worked fine for one number animation but as soon as i add the second animation with second script the first number dosen't animate. Is there a clash of functions?? 
thanks.
here is the Js script

```
<script>
$(function () {
    var ele = $('#num1');
    var clr = null;
    var rand = 0;//Starting Point
    (loop = function () {
        clearTimeout(clr);
        (inloop = function () {
            ele.html(rand += 1);
            if (!(rand % 60)) {  //20 is the Finished Value
                return;
            }
            clr = setTimeout(inloop, 32); //SPEED OF ANIMATION
        })();
        //  setTimeout(loop, 2500); //Increment Loop TIme
    })();
});
```

And the html

```
     <div id="num1"></div>
```

Now i add the second script with #num2 instead on #num1 and with a div  num2. but the problem occurs. thanks. please help me. greatly appriciated.

Comment: Here's what you have, before adding num2.  http://jsfiddle.net/6VHYT/

Comment: Are you trying to do the same thing, just for another div as well?  What I mean is, do you want them both incrementing to the same value and with the same speed?

Comment: I fixed it by clarifying the code somewhat... looks like others might have, too.  http://jsfiddle.net/6VHYT/7/

Comment: I've used text animation quite a bit for a free, unofficial loan modification calculator at www.armdisarm.com, see GPL source code at  https://github.com/DrPaulBrewer/Unofficial-Loan-Modification-HAMP --- this may give you some ideas of other things that are easy to do like use different colors or display extra messages as the animation progresses.

Answer (score 1):

Declare loop and inloop variables using var keyword to resolve this problem. This will make the variables local in scope as currently they are in global scope(as you are not using var).

```
$(function () {
var ele = $('#num1');
var clr = null;
var rand = 0;//Starting Point
var loop;
(loop = function () {
    var inloop;
    clearTimeout(clr);
    (inloop = function () {
        ele.html(rand += 1);
        if (!(rand % 60)) {  //20 is the Finished Value
            return;
        }
        clr = setTimeout(inloop, 32); //SPEED OF ANIMATION
    })();
    //  setTimeout(loop, 2500); //Increment Loop TIme
})();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's your code, only cleaned up a little bit and turned into a function so it can be used multiple times.  I see several answers, but I think you can look at this and learn what you could have done differently to make the code clearer, easier to use, more reliable.

http://jsfiddle.net/6VHYT/7/

```
$(function () {
    // it is bad to copy/paste code, so lets put a function here
    function risingNumber(start,end,jqstr,speed){
        // speed is optional, others required
        var clr = null;
        var ele = $(jqstr);
        var rand = start;//Starting Point
        if (arguments.length<3) throw "risingNumber needs 3 params";
        // note new functions to replace potentially confusing use of inline
        // and use of var to make a local, not global
        function loop() {
            clearTimeout(clr);
            function inloop() {
                ele.html(rand += 1);
                if (!(rand < end)) {  //end is the Finished Value
                    return;
                }
                clr = setTimeout(inloop, (speed || 32)); //SPEED OF ANIMATION
            };
            inloop();
            //  setTimeout(loop, 2500); //Increment Loop TIme
        };
        loop();
    }
    risingNumber(0,60,'#num1');
    risingNumber(0,100,'#num2');

});
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but what about if i want to have different speed for the two. an i make a new function like risingNumber2? And how can i delay a function like eg. when one ends second starts..Thanks

Comment: Hey dude, it's jerking animation. i don't know why and somehow it start s again and again

Comment: Although the 4th parameter is marked, 'speed', it is actually delay between changes in milliseconds.  So bigger numbers make it slower.  risingNumber(0,60,'#div2', 100); would do 100ms changes (or 10 per second) for #div2.  You could add a callback parameter after speed and test if it is a function and then call it on the "return ;" line.  I don't have the rest of your code, so can't debug it, but some devices are slow and GC and other stuff can get in the way.  This is all the time I have to help you on this.  Good luck!

Comment: oh yeah now i get it, i was using 2 scripts, one internal and one External. What i mistake :) Anyway thanks again.

Comment: One last Question how i can set if one animation ends then another starts, thanks.

Comment: Try adding "callback" to the end of the function risingNumber( ) parameter list, and then on the if block where end is tested, change return to to return callback().  Then when you call the first risingNumber, provide a function for callback that calls the second one.  If this still sounds too complicated, this would make another good SO question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle that might help you out: http://jsfiddle.net/gQeeR/

```
$(function () {
    function loop(selector) {
        var count = 0;
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            $(selector).html(count++);
            if (!(count % 60))  {
                $(selector).html(count);
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, 32);
    }
    loop('#num1');
    loop('#num2');
});
```

Comment: One Question, How can i set different numbers for #num1, #num2

Comment: Add an additional argument in the `loop` function.

Comment: you mean like this   loop('#num1',133)

Comment: you have to implement the additional argument in the function, but yes, thats the idea.